# Some settings in properties > world are missing?

Tags: rendering, interface, world

In my world setup (right bar) I can not access all the options I can as shown on the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:DE/2.6/Manual/World) on the right.

On my screen it looks like this:

[image: World Setup Right Bar]

For example, environment lighting, gather, indirect lighting, ambient occlusion mode (add, multiply), and the entire world tab (horizon, zenith color) are all missing.

And there is something else.
About 15 minutes ago I wanted to write this post but when I switched back to blender to look for the properties that are missing all properties where there.

So I thought 'Ok great' but now everything is missing again.
And I don't know why they suddenly appeared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you are using *[Cycles](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles)* as your render engine.

[Here is the correct wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/World).

Those settings you saw are only there when [*Blender Render*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render#Rendering) (also known as *Blender Internal* or *BI*) is selected as the active render engine in the *Info panel > Header*:

[image]

Note you *can* do everything that you could do using those settings in BI in Cycles, however the process for setting some of the things up is different in Cycles.

---

- The number of samples is controlled in *Properties > Render settings > Sampling*:

  [image]

  Note that samples behave differently in cycles and BI, see [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4980/599).
- AO in cycles is always *added*, if you want to *multiply* you must enable the AO pass in *Render Layers > Passes*:

  [image]

  And then multiply it with your render in the compositor:

  [image: Example image]
- The world background color can be set either from the world settings or the world nodes:

  [image]

  Both settings are the same, setting one sets the other. If you want sky textures or gradients, use [*Texture*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Textures) and *[Mapping](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/More#Mapping)* nodes.

Comment: @ gandalf3 Wow thanks a lot!!! So, could you tell me where I can find these settings I can use in Blender Render in Cycles? Or does this all work with nodes in cycles?

Comment: @BlenderShark It depends on the setting (yes, most require nodes). If you say exactly what you want to do, (multiply AO, world background, etc.) I'll see if I can add it to my answer.

Comment: 3 thanks for your effort. I want to add a background color, change the ambient occlusion mode (add or multiply) and the number of samples.

Comment: WOW THANKS A LOT!!! THIS REALLY HELPED ME. I would give you a vote up, but i am too Löw Reputation. Sorry for that but Norweger THANKS!