# Render shadow on transparent background with Blender Render

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I need to render a model on a transparent background. The models have a light source so they should be casting a shadow on a surface (the XY plane). The purpose for this is to overlay the rendered images (out of blender) on an image of the actual surface, so I want to generate the render *including* a semi-transparent shadow.

I don´t have any problem rendering the models on transparent background, but I can not make a shadow appear. I tried adding a surface below the model so the shadow can fall on it, but now there's the problem of keeping the surface from rendering.

How can I render the shadow on a transparent background?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On the shadow catcher object, add a material and enable *Shadows only* in *Material > Shadow*:

[image]

This will make it so that only the shadows cast on the object are shown, the rest of the surface will be invisible, showing the sky behind it.

If you set the alpha to *Transparent* in *Render settings > Shading*, the sky will be rendered as image transparency.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks :)

Comment: Newb here. I don't see the surface, Wire, volume, Halo tabs. I have blender  version 2.71

Comment: @DavidSilvaSmith Make sure you have the [render engine set to *Blender Internal*](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6754/599) and that you have created a material

Comment: Do you have a solution for how to do that in Cycles engine? I asked here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47569/render-shadows-on-object-b-but-not-object-b

Comment: @fabriced There are [numerous workarounds](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/19765/599), but there is no true equivalent in cycles. Yet. It's [currently being developed](https://developer.blender.org/D1788), and hopefully will be part of the 2.8x project

Comment: Thanks for that gandalf3 !  I've been wrestling with that and was about to fabricate an object to emulate a shadow!

Comment: Just a comment for people in 2021. There is now (2.93.x at least) an option in the "Object Properties" tab of the shadow catcher, under the "Visibility" section. The checkbox is called "Mask -> Shadow Catcher" and does exactly what was asked. The world background can be made transparent in "Render properties -> Film -> Transparent"