# How can I render only shadow in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I've been trying to render only shadows in Cycles, is that possible? If so, how?

For example, when I render a character, I want Cycles to render only the shadow of the character.

Comment: Shadow catcher: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19765/cycles-shadeless-shadow-catcher-material-for-rendering-onto-footage/19767#19767

Comment: Did you already tried the "Shadow" pass?

Comment: Andrew has a tutorial about that: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjWoglMYXBE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjWoglMYXBE) Its not exactly like BI shadow only material, but it has a similar effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is where you want to go.... but:

.blend: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzf8haoxrs6yfwv/special_case.blend?dl=0

[image]

produces:

[image]

Here's why I called the file "special_case": the ground plane extends beyond the edge of the camera, and produces a shadow png. If the ground plane edges are inside the camera view, you will see a thin black line at the mesh edge. I am sure there is a way to eliminate it, but darned if I can figure out.   Also, the masking box is a bit of a cheat.... but works for a still image. See .blend file for results. Node tree set-up here:

[image]

Comment: instead of just a file please summarize the steps taken. If the link to your file disappears the answer will be useless.

Comment: Also please add an explanation to your images and the logic behind the node tree you propose.

Comment: I found this very useful but cegaton is correct more details would be very helpful. I spent about an hour trying to get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 8):

A [shadow catcher](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/object_settings/object_data.html) was added in blender [2.79](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/Cycles#Shadow_Catcher).

There is no reason to use compositor tricks any longer to generate a shadow. You simply add an object (In my case a simple plane) and check the *Shadow Catcher* box.

Go to the *Object* tab of the *Properties Editor*. In 2.79 the *Shadow Catcher* option is in the *Cycles Settings* section. In 2.8 the *Shadow Catcher* option is in the *Visibility* section.

[image: 2.79] [image: 2.8]

Here is what my rendered scene looks like so far.
[image: rendered scene with object and shadow catcher plane]

Now to get *just the shadow* you need to disable the *Camera* visibility on all the other objects. This setting is in nearly the same place as the shadow catcher. Go to *Object* tab of the *Properties Editor*. In 2.79 it's under the *Cycles Settings* section. In 2.8 it is in the *Ray Visibility* subsection of the *Visibility* section.

[image: 2.79] [image: 2.8]

[image: just the shadows now]