# How to denoise animations using Blender's Temporal Denoiser?

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes, render-layers, denoise

I've been diving into the secret Blender Animation Denoiser function mentioned [in February of 2019 by Pablo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inlm6Emh3tc&t=1232s) and documented on the [Developer Site](https://developer.blender.org/D3889).

Here are some things I figured out after digging around:

1. When you render for the animation denoiser you have to use OpenEXR Multilayer.
2. I then enabled denoising within the Blender view layer settings panel, like instructed.

My code looks like this:

```
bpy.ops.cycles.denoise_animation(output_filepath="//Render\Denoised Sequence\Denoised_Images_")
```

After hitting enter on the above command, it worked!!!!.... except it didn't.

[image: This is what the console did, which looked like it worked!]

It went through the process of creating the images of the new denoised sequence.  But when I open the files... they are not denoised.  Simply exact copies of the original noisy images.

So close, yet I don't know where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: Recommend using intels ai denoiser in the compositor (denoise node), which gives way better results anyway [Type of Denoiser built into Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178257/type-of-denoiser-built-into-blender/178330#178330).

Comment: It may, however the potential beauty of this denoiser workflow is that it is temporal.  It will scan across multiple frames and denoise in a way that will eliminate flickering between frames, which is currently a problem that I run into with either of the frame denoiser options in Blender now when rendering animations.  I haven't actually seen results from the animation denoiser to compare, so I can't know for sure which is better, but I can say that denoising on some of my scenes with the frame denoiser just gives too much flickering effect, at least for my taste.

Comment: Can confirm. Blender crashes on the last frame and the "combined" pass in the resulting exr files shows exactly the same as the "noisy image" pass. Suggest to file a bug report.

Answer (score 12):

### How to use the Temporal Denoiser

**Step 01: Pack Denoising Data**

1. Enable denoising data in *View Layer > Passes > Denoising Data*
2. Set file format to *OpenEXR Multilayer* (so Blender packs the denoising data)
3. Render your animation

> **Note:**
> Blender 2.8 needs to be used in the pipeline to pack the denoising data. Simply open your .blend with [Blender 2.8](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/), set up the denoising data and save. Then you can reopen the file and render with any version.

[image]

**Step 02: Denoising**

```
import bpy
import os 
import glob

inputdir="D:/Animation/"
outputdir="D:/Animation/Denoised_"
os.chdir(inputdir)
myfiles=(glob.glob("*.exr"))
for file in myfiles:
   print(inputdir + file + " to " + outputdir + file)
   bpy.ops.cycles.denoise_animation(input_filepath=(inputdir + file), output_filepath=(outputdir + file))
```

1. Copy the above script into Blender's *Text Editor* (and backup your animation files :)
2. Change the location to where your rendered files are. The default location is `D:/Animation/`
3. Run the script by pressing the Play button <kbd>►</kbd>

[image]

---

Notes: The used code is from [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/dsk9fr/temporal_denoising_animations_in_blender_280_in/). All credits to [toadfury](https://www.reddit.com/user/toadfury/).

Comment: Why doesn't this work with 2.9x? Is there a way to make it render the denoise data?

Comment: Hey, good news :). I re-rendered the animation with 2.9 and Denoising seems to work just fine now. Must've been some hiccup in the previous render.

Comment: I tried this code on several different versions of Blender but I don't see any differences at all. Are there specific versions of Blender that work/don't work? Or was there anything else that you found that made it not work properly?

Comment: Hello @Alex :). Just make sure you pack the denoising data (Step 1), doesn't work without it. I used this method in 2.8 - 2.9 without problems. P.S. An addon would be a really, *really* sweet thing :).

Comment: I definitely did that, but I'll try again, following the steps, who knows maybe I did miss something.

Comment: @JachymMichal, Still not working. Do you want to try the addon out and see if it works? Here is a dropbox link for the work-in-progress addon, it will expire at the end of this week.

https://www.dropbox.com/t/JTJuSCNyDl6WTdjt

It's pretty simple, install it like any addon, it will be in the "N menu".

"Setup Denoiser" does this:
Creates folders "Animation" and "Denoised" where the .blend file is, sets the denoise data pass on, sets the file type to EXR, .piz compression, and turns off the Regular Denoiser. 

Render then press "Denoise", which runs the script and exports to "Denoise".

Comment: @JachymMichal Were you able to test it? I just realized that link expired, this one won't expire for a month. 

https://www.dropbox.com/t/qDfMgJY94Nyhi8T5

Comment: Hey @Alex :). I totally forgot to test it last week, but I'll get back to you with the results asap. Sorry about that :).

Comment: Hey @Alex, just tested your addon! It works perfectly for denoising my files. However I can't get it to output files containing denoise data :). Not currently sure why...

Comment: Hello @AlexPearce :). I did some tests, and it turns out you need Blender 2.8 to pack the denoising data. I added an explanation to the original post.

Answer (score 4):

I also struggled to get this working on 2.9x - until I found this!
The Super Image Denoiser (SID) is a free add-on that employs temporal denoising. It produces high quality results using a similar process as the one described above, except with easy buttons instead of script. It also well offers customization to compensate for artifacts.

I used it and it works perfectly well. You can download it from GumRoad for free/donation:
https://gumroad.com/l/SuperImageDenoiser

Good luck!

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing :)

Comment: I'm having issues with this on Blender 3.0 . Anyone else having this problem, and know the fix?

This is the error i'm getting ->
KeyError:"bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Noisy Image" not found"

Answer (score 0):

I think that for the `bpy.ops.cycles.denoise_animation()` command to work properly, you also need to enable the vector pass. Otherwise you get pretty much the same pattern with the regular denoiser. Try that and see if you see any changes in the denoised result.

Check this article in the Features section:

https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.1/Cycles