# Exporting a Denoised Composited Image Sequence

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes, denoise

I just finished Blender Guru's donut tutorial, all parts and levels. However I must have misunderstood how the composite node works, especially in regards to animation (or rather image sequences).

[image]

So I rendered the entire animation. The animation has a lot of noises, and as I understand it, for the denoise to work it needs to render first.

After I rendered it, I've imported it as an image sequence in the node viewer, and linked it to the image dot of the denoise node.

Now what do I do? I've tried re-rendering it, but it still renders the noisy renders. I must be missing a function or something that will trigger the composite to render out the sequence. As it is now, I have to save each frame as an image in the image editor. That can't be right?

Comment: Hello :). Why not denoise the animation as you render it the first time?

Comment: Note that the information from the render layers is in *scene referred* values (linear, unbound values), while that in pngs is in *display referred* values (with a transfer function , or  gamma curve, applied and limited to 0-1 value), so **they are not the same kind of information**. If you are going to  do any kind of post processing to the images use OpenEXR as file format, so that you can not only preserve the original values, but you can also save the render passes that you might need later on. As for denoising read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181921/

Comment: @JachymMichal I would if I knew how. According to the Blender Guru tutorial, as I understand it, you have to attach the denoise node, render, and then apply the composite to the renders. You can't just render out a clean version. He didn't say you couldn't specifically, but he never clarified the steps to render. Just, add the node, render your sequence. But when I do that, the renders that come out have noise. I have to composite each frame one at a time and save them. I must be doing something wrong

Comment: @susu I've found that blender page you linked, but that's not my problem. I'm super introductory and am not trying to code anything. I would just like to export my frames as denoised pngs. Is that not possible without programming and coding? I understand theres a lot more I can do, but I'm just trying to get a simple export for now so I can move onto to my next project.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I'm so proud! I turned on composite in the Output properties under post-processing,

Now when I render the pngs the render says "initializing execution" and the final image is noise free! I look forward to learning about EXRs etc, but I'm just trying to do this one step at a time haha.

Thanks @JachymMicha and @susu!