# Rendering with compositor only renders single image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, image, compositing-nodes

I am currently trying to render out an image sequence that I imported into Blender's compositor and put a denoise node to. I set the start frame to 1 and the correct amount of frame length and offset. When I render the animation, it re-renders over the original image sequence which is fine, but it only renders the last frame of the sequence over each image. I then have to re-render the image sequence since it basically replaced my image sequence with a single image.
Does anyone know how to help?

Here are my compositor settings:
[image]

The offset is set to 116 because thats when the image sequence and animation begin.

Comment: Why do you have the offset to 116?

Comment: Because thats where my animation begins.

Comment: So my original image sequence I rendered was frames 117-130, I then imported that image sequence into the compositor and added a denoise node. I want to rerender those frames using the denoise node and the compositor

Comment: How did you set the frame range to be rendered in the output settings?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I have the timeline set to the specified 14 frames I want rendered...

Comment: from 1 to 14? please show an image of the render settings

Comment: Ok I edited the post with the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is this you are setting the offset to 116, but the start frame is set to 1, so the 14 frames you want to render would be rendered in frames 1 to 14. Otherwise you are getting a repeat of the last frame.

[image]

On a side note, it is quite unfortunate that you chose to use png as image format, by doing so you've lost a lot of the information that would help you denoise the image. In the future use EXR mulilayer and save the denoise passes.

Comment: Read: [How to denoise animations using blender's temporal denoiser](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181921/how-to-denoise-animations-using-blenders-temporal-denoiser)