# How to properly denoise an animation [local and renderfarm]

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, denoise, .exr

I have a project for my college assingment that has to be ready at end of march. I am still "new" to blender but I try my best in every way, so:
I have a scene with 400 frames that uses Cycles and a sampling rate of 500 (If necessary I can lower this). I used different Denoise options **[OID, NLM, OPTIX]** but all these are not really suitable for animations and are messing up volumetrics (Or did i something wrong?). I found the addon **SuperImageDenoise (SID)**, This works wonders with still images and should work very good with animations. The problem is, this scene takes days ony my computer to render and denoise.
Is there a other way to denoise an animation on my pc? Which render format should I use for this? (I use PNG but SID uses some sort of EXR files.)

I also searched for render farms that support some sort of denoising for animations, but I just can not find one. Some are using **OID** but I am not a huge fan of the **OID** denoise results. The maker of the **SuperImageDenoiser** says that if a renderfarm can ouput the frames as mlEXR files I could denoise them local on my machine.

How are you guys denoise your animations?

Do you guys have any ideas?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Related: [How to denoise animations using Blender's Temporal Denoiser?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/181921/78972)