# Settings or manual for temporal denoiser

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, denoise

I am looking for a manual or documentation or a way to change settings for the temporal denoiser for animation as described in this question:

[How to denoise animations using Blender's Temporal Denoiser?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181921/how-to-denoise-animations-using-blenders-temporal-denoiser)

While this denoising method is working nicely, I still would like to make adjustments if possible.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hello :). The temporal denoiser is using the Open Image Denoiser. It's the same one as used in the [Denoise Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/denoise.html#:~:text=The%20Denoise%20node%20is%20used,clean%20images%20with%20machine%20learning.)  There are no settings to tweak, unlike other denoisers.

Comment: It's partly because the Temporal denoiser isn't yet officially implemented - it was added to Blender to denoise the Spring Open movie, but doesn't even have any GUI interface :)

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for claryfying!