# How do I denoise an image sequence that has already been rendered?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes, denoise

I have completed Andrew's donut tutorial and I have a full set of 30 frames that makes up the image sequence. I opened another Blender tab (closing down the tutorial with saving) to compile the frames into a video. However, I forgot to denoise the frames.

Now when I go to the 'Compositing' tab and open the Image Editor, the 'Render Result' is completely blank. Is there any way to denoise the image sequence **without** having to re-render the whole sequence?

[image: Here is an image showing the Render Result as blank as well as my Compositor setup.]

Comment: This is only going to work when using [OpenEXR Multilayer](https://www.openexr.com/) along with denoising data enabled. What output format did you set? png?

Comment: Yes I used PNG as the output format. It says on the website that the OpenEXR is not suitable for lit 3D scenes with volumetric aspects, which is exactly what the scene is.

Comment: You can try to connect the image to the denoise node without using the *normal* and *albedo* sockets but the result won't that good as it could be. Just render to a multilayered exr next time which allows to store all the image passes into one file. BTW: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106670/compositors-corner-pin-node-does-something-odd-to-input-image/106671#106671

Comment: How would I render to a multilayered exr next time? I am new to this sorry.

Comment: Where did you read that EXR is not suitable? Quite the oppositie is true. The format that is useless png.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to connect the *image* (or *image sequence*) to the *denoise node* without using the *Normal* and *Albedo* sockets but **the result won't be as good as it could be**.

[image]

In general, [Intel's OpenImageDenoise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYKFN.png) is the [best option](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166271/31447) for now, see how to set it up properly: [**How to properly connect the Denoise node in Compositor?**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173761/31447). Alternativly, you can try using other software, see: [**Denoising Animations in Cycles**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/181546/31447).

---

Next time, I suggest enable *Denoising Data* and set the file format to *OpenEXR Multilayer* which allows to store any additional passes like *Denoising Normal*, *Denoising Albedo*, *etc.* to the image file as well (without doing anything), see: [**Save all render passes to EXR image?**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18406/31447)

[image]