# How to get rid of this distortion/heat waves in cycles animation render

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I am very curious right now.
I wanted to render a video about lights and there is that weird glitching heatwave everywhere where it's dark (look at the top around the orange object, dark sides are glitching).

I used default Cycles settings with OpenImageDenoiser and 64 samples. Is it due to denoiser that this is created? Any idea how to get rid of it? I, unfortunately, cannot give the whole file (due to 1GB size) but as I said, all render settings are default expect denoiser.

Every time camera is far away and it is dark these heatwaves are created.

Rendered with AMD Radeon 6700XT GPU

Each frame was rendered with 8 tiles 320x360px (whole res is 1280x720px)

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Yes it looks like the effect of denoising as it will calculate for each frame but won't try to make something coherent for animation, maybe try another denoiser mode?

Comment: Wonder which one is worth for videos, Do you have something to recommend? I will go and try NLM or nodes and then some addons

Comment: Have you tried through the Compositor? It works better than just enabling the option. I'm not sure it will fix your problem though

Comment: Yes I'm trying to render 30 test frames with compositor right now

Comment: maybe this answer will help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166307/denoising-animations-in-cycles

Comment: hmm nodes in compositor did same thing as before

Comment: *Short answer:* Your sample count is way too low for interior like that, bump it up to at least 250 and the artifacts will go away.