# (De)noise artifacts in animation

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, denoise

I have a simple scene with focal point animation, and when I render it there is some crazy movement in the highlights, that I'm pretty sure is due to the denoising, i.e. that the noise pattern changes when changing focus, and the denoising makes it look like something smooth that moves around.

[image]

The only way I've found so far to reduce the effect is (obviously) to increase the samples, but increasing the transmission samples from 16×1 to 16×100 (Cycles' branched path tracing) still doesn't look that good.

[image]

Is there some other smart trick to keep these shaky highlights fixed? Ore some setting I might have overlooked? I've tried [How to denoise animations using Blender's Temporal Denoiser?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181921/how-to-denoise-animations-using-blenders-temporal-denoiser), but it doesn't seem to work with Blender 2.93.5, and my scene won't open with 2.8.

I don't see the same kind of artifact in e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTWWlyOf8n8, but maybe his light placement didn't cause this sort of highlights, or he used many more samples with his beefy machine.

Comment: Hi :). Yes, this is caused by denoising. Andrew probably didn't use a denoiser in his early 2.8 version. Now there's a free temporal [SuperImageDenoiser addon on Gumroad](https://kevinlorengel.gumroad.com/l/SuperImageDenoiser) :))

Comment: @JachymMichal He did use a denoiser, at least he showed it in a previous chapter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lr8QnR5WWU&t=17m10s. I tried the SID addon in another machine and a previous render. I couldn't get it to work and it said the temporal denoise would be removed... maybe I should try again now that I know a bit more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Denoising Animations in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166307/denoising-animations-in-cycles)

Comment: @Crantisz Well, all suggested solutions are commercial, so they're not useful for me.