# Final rendered animation is really wierd

Tags: rendering, animation, 3d-view, shaders

My rendered animation is turning up really weird. I don`t even know how to explain the issue. The animation isn't smooth and it's glitchy...I guess.
I have turned up the resolution, changed the samples, removed the depth of field etc. And none of them helped. I am using cycles render.

Here`s a small clip of my render (for your understanding and shared via Google Drive)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1edwqi_gWVIZnjhxYG0VQb5z-F0PEU0Q_/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a denoise problem. The default denoise options currently offered in blender (AI, Optix and the original blender denoiser) produce jittering because they do only Spatial Denoising, meaning that they use only one frame for input, so all images are denoised separately. The main problem with this approach is that noise patterns might not be consistent or homogeneous from one frame to the next. Sometimes this kind of denoising might actually create more problems than using no denoising at all.

I wrote nice answer about video denoising software that you can use:

[Denoising Animations in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166307/denoising-animations-in-cycles/181546#181546)

You can also use a build in animation denoiser, but it only avaliable via comand line:

[How to denoise animations using Blender's Temporal Denoiser?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181921/how-to-denoise-animations-using-blenders-temporal-denoiser)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like denoising issues with not enough samples. Increasing sample amount should help.

Comment: It actually doesn't help unfortunately :(