# Denoising results in flickering on fur regardless of high sample count

Tags: denoise

Every time I render [this test animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V25CP.jpg), the denoising is resulting in different patterns of smoothing for each frame, making the flicker. Everyone online suggests upping the sample count, so I used 4096 samples, however I also had a noise threshold of 0.5 to decrease render times. I'm doing tests to figure out if the noise threshold was the problem, but I'm hoping I can find help faster since it takes hours to render just a few frames.

Comment: It's impossible to fix, until unless you go to CRAZY HIGH render samples. There is a blender guru YouTube tutorial about this problem and he tells about a software (which I think was free) that fixes this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Denoising Animations in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166307/denoising-animations-in-cycles)

Comment: @YousufChaudhry Unfortunately the program is not free, and neither are the other two mentioned in Jachym's linked post. Not only do the programs cost money, but you also need other editing software which also costs more money. It's a shame there doesn't seem to be a good free solution to this. At this point, I've done enough testing to determine that I can leave my poor laptop rendering for about 5 days in order to get a decent result on this 2 seconds gif :/

Comment: @LeoSchunn Which denoiser do you use? Blender's new and updated "Optix" Denoising solves the flickering problem anyways, as I have tested in many new animations and also on blender's documentation. Though you need an NVIDIA GPU for that. (They say it works only on RTX GPUs, but it works pretty well on my non RTX)

Comment: I haven't tried optix yet but I will! I have an Nvidia GPU, but it's a very weak GTX 1050 ti. Regardless, I'll give it a shot and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Flicker Free Denoising** this add-on is great a denoising animations without flicker even at very low sample rates. I've got 10-15 samples to work great!

Try it here: https://4917137779526.gumroad.com/l/FlickerFreeDenoising
[image]