# Grainy lights in Blender Cycles

Tags: rendering, materials, light, lighting, emission

I have this night scene and it's pretty clear that something is not right. The lights are strange, like muffled, making everything grainy. Does anyone have an idea that can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). This looks suspiciously like denoiser artifacts. Do you have any denoising enabled?

Comment: The visible bad res hdri is the issue to me.

Comment: Yes, I have the denoising node and denoise option enabled

Comment: Ok, and... Does disabling the denoiser resolve your issue? (asking because unclear what mean by "muffled")

Comment: Muffled in the sense of very grainy-looking

Comment: donìt look at the hdri, but look at the light on the desk or on the walls, it's really strange

Comment: Easy, then it is the denoiser... @VikSn0w Use Intels denoiser in the compositor and bump up the samples to at least 500.

Comment: I disabled the denoising node, leaving the standard denoising on, let's see

Comment: Only use one of them -> The node in the compositor (as mentioned), read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166271/31447