# Denoise not working in Blender Octane

Tags: rendering, denoise, octane-render-engine

I'm using Blender Octane, but somehow the denoise doesn't work in render
I have it enabled, also connect the denoise beauty socket, but nothing worked, I need help...
[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess octane is using nvidia's optix denoiser and for that your graphics card is way too old. Try to use intel's denoiser in the compositor. If that's the case, should be reported to otoy to give an error message at least.

Comment: Do you mean Intel's ML Compositing Node or Nvidia D-noise ??

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166271/31447 Again, D-Noise won't work for you (optix too)

Comment: Related to the link by @brockmann : [How to connect the Denoise node in Compositor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/173760/)