# Does Blender 2.8 Automatically Denoise Renders in Cycles - Where are the settings?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

When I render with Cycles the render is denoised automatically without selecting Denoise under the View Layer Properties - is this normal?

If it denoises automatically, are there any settings for this?

Thanks,
N

Comment: Related: [Type of Denoiser built into Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/178257/78972) and [Which denoiser is better?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/166269/78972)

Comment: It doesn't denoise automatically. Perhaps you enabled denoising in compositor? :)