# Settings to improve animation render speed

Tags: rendering

My system is very underpowered. But I’m hoping, someone might be able to tell me what settings I could use to get the best outcome.

I’m using Blender to create a 3D version of my band's logo. I want to animate the camera rotating around the logo, but up close, just viewing small sections at a time. The animation has a particle plane (that uses three circles to animate floating embers).

I started a real small render (100 frames last night... and I’m estimating it to take 15 hours, for approximately 4 seconds of animation)

My system is iMac 21.5inch, late 2013
2.7ghz quad core intel core i5
8gb ram 1600 MHz ddr3
Graphics - Intel iris pro 1536 mb

Engine is cycles on CPU
Light bounce total set at 2
Tiles set to 16x16
Resolution 1920px x 1080px
24fps
Sampling is set at “render 200”
Format is set to avi jpeg
Quality 80%

Because it’s for social media (insta and Facebook) can I maybe get away with reducing certain things? Or changing settings somewhere to speed up the render?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52559/how-to-render-a-scene-faster-in-cycles

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the Eevee render engine, which is much faster than Cycles.

It is less photo-realistic, but it seems to me that photo-realism is likely not a requirement for your logo.

To switch renderers, go to the Render Properties tab, and select "Eevee" in the Render Engine dropdown.

Comment: Ohh really, I thought cycles was faster? Just going off one YouTube tutorial

Comment: Nope, Eevee is much faster. Eevee uses rasterization instead of raytracing, making it almost realtime. Give it a try - the two engines are compatible, so you won't need to change much besides the renderer.

Comment: Amazing! It actually looks better in eevee and took 5 mins to render  thank you 