# how do I animate my very complex model?

Tags: animation

Hi I just signed up and I am in dire need of help animating something! I modeled a combine harvester in quite a lot of detail, and I'd like it to drive from point A to point B, passing lots of stuff along the way. It seems the file is already too heavy for my macbook air with 8gb of ram. When I press the space bar to watch the combine go, it very slowly staggers through the scene. It's not able to play at 24fps.

The file is 320 megabytes and contains only the combine harvester, which is made up of 1,150 objects and 10,000,000 triangles. How can I continue with my project of making an animation with the combine when I can't even watch it go smoothly?

Thanks very much.

Comment: It seems you already answered your question "the file is already too heavy for your hardware". Optimization techniques exist for a reason. You can hide most of your objects and work on the rest. You could also replace those objects with some placeholders or simplified versions temporarily while working on the project.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: The art of 3D modelling and rendering is one of "lying", where the goal is to try to achieve the look you are aiming for with as little effort and resources as possible. Failing that you need to either lower your expectations to match your hardware, or improve your hardware to match your expectations. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52559/how-to-render-a-scene-faster-in-cycles/52561#52561

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for the input. Thanks to everyone. The model I made is my first, and I made it as realistic as I could and made it too complex. I made a lot of objects, so I joined them all together to make just a few to parent them to an empty and more easily manipulate the whole model. While I work on the animation I will do as jeff lange suggested, and set the draw type of the combine as bounds. As I combined all of those objects together I applied a lot of subsurface modifiers which made the file heavier. This was unavoidable, am I right? Cheers!

Comment: @jerryjenkins if you grouped together objects that have the same subsurface modifier settings, you wouldn't need to apply the modifier. You can also disable that modifier in viewport entirely so it's easier to work on your project.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusvonBroady. I hadn't thought of that. It seems there's a lot I hadn't thought of!