# Blender 3D with python. Is it possible to render video in blender by running it in -background, apart from frame-by-frame rendering and merging

Tags: rendering, animation, video

I have a server that starts the rendering of a certain model with a script. 1 frame is rendered ~3 seconds, it turns out that for a five-second video it takes about 120 frames, which takes a very large amount of time. Are there other possibilities for implementation?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52559/how-to-render-a-scene-faster-in-cycles

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
blender -b <blend-file> -P <python-script> -a
```

- `-b` is telling blender to run in background mode
- `-P` is for python script to run
- `-a` is to start animation render

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't express myself clearly
This is what I am using now
I want to know if there is a faster way