Slowly rendering
I'm new to animation in Blender, my projects take a few days to render even if my PC isn't stressed. My configuration is not bad: RTX 3070/I9/64 RAM.
I started doing a liquid simulation too and it took longer. I would like to know if there is a plugin or software to render faster or if this rendering time is normal for animation?

Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52559/how-to-render-a-scene-faster-in-cycles/52561?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C0.0000#52561

I change the question, thanks

does the link above answer your question

Hello and welcome. You question is very broad. Render times are different depending on different factors, how big your scene is, how many objects are in scene at the same time, how much details do objects have; in the case of particles the amount of particles, the physics, also lights, reflections, materials, effects and many things.
