# Change things between render layers?

Tags: rendering, render-layers

I have two render layers. I want to change some properties, such as object visibility, material settings, etc between these layers. Is there any way for me to do this? I am not looking for a situation specific way to do this, I want a general way to change properties between layers.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background

Comment: A shadow catcher? http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19767/3710

Comment: This is the most useful "marked as duplicate" that I've had in a long time. Thanks!