# How to cast object shadow only and mask the shadow of the object with the object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows, masking

I have an object sitting (clipping a bit) on the plane. I can achieve the shadow only via the node tree. But I want the object itself to mask the shadow. I mocked up what I want in photoshop for clarity. The holdout cuts an alpha hole through everything so that doesn't work. I'm guessing there's some light path and transparency node arrangement possible or maybe it's doable in compositing? Thanks for any help!

[image]

I have this:
[image]

I can do this:
[image]

I want this:
[image]

Comment: Render Layers > Passes > Shadow? It depends what do you need to achieve in real.

Comment: Agree with @vklidu, this way you'll get a quick shadow pass which you can multiply on top of the background or use as mask for your grade. You can also use the shadow catcher option per object. However, the problem with the shadow catcher is that, it does not preserve indirect light values -> In real life the shadow is slighly tinted in the color of the object (blue in your case) so for the most realistic result, it's getting a bit complicated, see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19767/31447), unfortunatly it's not updated for 2.8+ versions yet, but the principle is the same.

Comment: This will work! I was hoping I could achieve this inside the viewport so I can see it as I work. But this gets the job done - thanks!