# change background color from script

Tags: scripting

How to do this: [Render shadow on transparent background with Blender Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14898/render-shadow-on-transparent-background-on-blender-render) from script? I need to set a transparent background color before render a mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hover over a property, you can see its Python property.

Here, it is simply :

```
scene.render.alpha_mode = 'SKY' # in ['TRANSPARENT', 'SKY']
```