# Ground Transparent but keeping Shadows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-layers, shadows, render-passes

Say I have a cube on a plane:

[image]

How do I make the ground transparent but also keeping the shadow that the cube passes? I want a solid shadow, not a transparent shadow as other answers detail. Like this:

[image]

I need the answer in blender cycles.

Comment: Does this help - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47569/render-shadows-over-a-transparent-background-in-cycles?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background/26686#26686 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19765/cycles-shadeless-shadow-catcher-material-for-rendering-onto-footage and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14898/render-shadow-on-transparent-background-with-blender-render/14900#14900 and