# How to catch light without the object it is hitting on for compositing? (2.80)

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers

I want to render a neon sign along with its emitting light on the wall behind. Then composite it to a real video with Camera Match.
I suppose I'd need to render the light with transparency (somehow). But how exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I render a spotlight hitting a transparent wall?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130277/how-can-i-render-a-spotlight-hitting-a-transparent-wall)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19765/cycles-shadeless-shadow-catcher-material-for-rendering-onto-footage and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14898/render-shadow-on-transparent-background-with-blender-render/

Comment: I'm glad you brought this to my attention Duarte. Any chance you could delete the other one?

Comment: I can't delete them myself, directly, but I can flag it for moderation; but since you authored the post you should be able to delete it yourself

Comment: I think the best lead so far is this one: "what you need is the emission pass, youll need to place the plane on the position of your wall and activate the emmision pass from the cycles render settings, you can the extract the pass from the render layer node and use it to composite the emmission onto your footage. you should be able to extract the shadow pass too so you shouldnt need to have a seperate plane for both shadows and emmission" from Chris (cgjam.net)