# Baking In Cycles creates noisy result

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

Whenever I try to bake a Ambient Occlusion map (no matter the scale), I get a noisy result (like that of a TV set with bad reception). Is there anyway to fix this??
This is a AO Bake of an object i'm working on, yet when I baked it at 2048x2048, the AO was very noisy/grainy.

Click image for full size.
[image: baked image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/18xjP.png UV in full resolution.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4980/599

Answer (score 9):

That's probably because a low number of samples. Cycles uses samples to render and to bake. Turn up your samples in the Properties window under the Samples heading.

Comment: Ohh!!! I didn't know sampling still effected baking! awesome! thank you!

Comment: No problem! If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer on the left. ;)