# Cycle render noise wont change

Tags: cycles-render-engine

i have watched many tutorials on how to reduce noise in cycles. however, no matter what i do its still grossly overflowing with fireflies. i must be missing something basic but i dont know what it is. i was watching a tutorial where he put the emitter plane in a hallway and changed its location and size and it made it crystal clear. i tried this and it just makes it worse. i have no idea what i am doing wrong.

Here is the tutorial i was watching.i was just trying to recreate the first example.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81k22ijYiIw

[image: emitter problem]

Comment: In your image there are no firefies, just noise.... 10 samples is too low... try rendering at 100 or 200 or more. Please read this post on how to reduce noise in cycles: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles

Comment: In a addition to that, you're trying to light a large space with a small light source. This will give noisy results.

Answer (score 0):

I see that You set render samples to only 10 but used an emission node.. so I suppose You are trying to get a shadeless material..

the correct node setup for this kind of result is this:

[image: shadeless]

don't really need for a 100 emission size, just 1 to 3 ^^

If You are trying to reach a different kind of result so... raise up your samples to 200 up to 1000 to archive much better results in cycles :)