# Black pixels in render when using Cycles material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I already tried adding more subivisions, tweaked the light bouncing parameters, etc, but I cannot get rid of the black pixels when using  Cycles material copied from a YouTube video.

[image]

Here is the source if someone wants to check it out:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1541106/spots.blend

Thanks!

Comment: Those can be partially [noise caused by render settings](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles), partially black light bouncing from the background.

Comment: What GPU are you using?

Comment: @cegaton Nvidia GTS250 under Archlinuxx64, with 340xx drivers.

Comment: @MrZak i had the world background set to black, set it to white and the same thing happens. edit:i even "disabled" it.

Comment: Actually your file crashed Blender for me because of OpenSL usage.. However anyway I don't have any of those black pixels rendering on CPU. Rendering on GPU could be one which causing the problem (although I can't test that).

Comment: @MrZak i actually am CPU rendering.

Comment: GPU rendering here and no black noise to speak of, you just have to let your render calculate more samples over time, although you do have a very small frequency noise texture affecting your material normal. That is bound to cause some noise, especially having the *Factor* black and white socket affecting normals which may cause issues. Subdivisions won't help here, only make it worse

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting those spots when I render the scene.  Perhaps try rendering with the CPU instead of the GPU.

I rendered with the CPU.  My results:
[image]

Comment: Actually, i'm struggling with getting CUDA to work on my system and i'm currently working with CPU.

Comment: Your card is quite old, do not bother with CUDA. Support for cuda v1 was dropped a in blender a while ago.

Comment: @cegaton perhaps you are refering to CUDA v7 which dropped v1. CUDA, because i found nothing related in Blender. 6.5 should work fine with my card.

Comment: I meant CUDA compute capability. Quote Form the [blender manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#cuda):  We support graphics cards starting from GTX 4xx (computing capability 2.0).
[List of CUDA cards with shader model](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) The mentioned card has a 1.1 cuda capability see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA

Comment: @cegaton oh, i see, bummer. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score -2):

Have you happened to read ? https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/

When I use glossy shaders, I get a lot noise like stuff, and stuff from this article has helped me a lot.

Based on the screen caps, because the file actually crashed for me, I noticed your samples look kinda low. If your willing to let your computer crunch for awhile, up the samples and picture should look better.

And I never rely on the viewport rendering, that gives you a rough idea how it all come out, and lets you change things in real time because it isn't going ham on making a purty picture. But if your going to submit this to something, you gotta see the finished polished product.

Hope this helps.