# How can I get the smoke in the render to look like it does in the viewport?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am new to blender, I have smoke rendering problem please help me.
In viewport the smoke looking very nice and realistic:

[image]

But when I render it looks completely unrealistic and looks noisy:

[image: view port and render]

Please someone tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: You use cycles render correct?

Comment: Well your render looks "correct" to me. If you want shadows that are less harsh (the only difference I can find between rendered and your top image) then please edit your question and make that distinction.

Comment: the top image look very realastic but rendered image have some noisy dark points.

Comment: The "noise" in cycles is a common problem, read the answers to [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4980/935)

Answer (score 1):

Increase the smoke resolution (divisions) and increse render samples,also set clamp indirect to something around 3. Check smoke high-res and experiment with divisions and strenght!