# how to remove noise? Sample and Light paths do not change anything!

Tags: rendering, light, noise-reduction

Same result regardless of the type of lighting.

[image: Sword noise]

[image]

Comment: Sample and Light paths do not change anything !

Comment: There's not enough information here. Please edit your question and add an image of your render settings. You might add how your lighting is set up as well.

Comment: is the sample rate at 10? because that might not be high enough.

Comment: Same at 100-200-1000

Comment: add also details about materials and nodes used, or uplaod the model (or part of it) for others to share... (eg: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), but check also many other similar questions, to learn from comments and answers.

Comment: 100 (10 square) samples is too low! try a higher number .

Comment: Make sure you're changing the Render samples and the Preview samples. Preview is for viewport renders (rendered shading mode), Render is for actual final renders (F12).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, graphic driver update (AMD CRIMSON 16.6) on Amd 7870 Card

Now i get this when i make a render (gpu) .... (same sword)

[image]

Same render with CPU (Fx-8320)

[image]

Comment: The [amd 7870 is listed as supported](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/OpenCL) though the list looks like it may be a bit out of date now. I would suggest [reporting it as a bug](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/) to at least let the devs know that the amd render gave a different result to cpu and that the driver update breaks gpu rendering.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on BlenderGuru.com about how to get rid of fireflies (or noise) in cycles, I hope it helps.

http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/

By Andrew price