# Black dust in animation render output

Tags: rendering

I am new to Blender, and had been playing around testing.
I have this problem now that I can't figure out what is wrong.  I get very clean, no black dusts in a single image output, but I get very very dusty images when I do an animation output render.

Why is this happening???

[image]
[image]

Comment: Those are usually called firefly's and the are because either A. to low sample on your output, or B. darkness. And the darkness gets fireflys because of the low sample output. So really, just turn up the sample rate

Comment: This should help http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4980/26541

Comment: @SammySwanson  Hi, thanks for your comment.  But I still don't understand why I will get these fireflys only in the animation render output and not in single picture render output, when all the settings were exactly the same.  As you can see in the second picture, it came out perfectly clean...?

Comment: that is strange but maybe its because that white object in the first picture light? obstacle? isn't present in the second

Comment: @SammySwanson  I can't figure out why.  I guess I will try baking fluid simulation again and see.  Thanks for your help though!