# How do you make a lot of noise in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a scene where I want a lot of noise, but noise generated by cycles, so it is coherent with the colors behind. Thus, I want to generate a lot of noise in cycles without using things such as noise textures. Can someone give me tricks to have a lot of noise naturally created by cycles for a scene with a relatively small object count?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add an image that exemplifies what you are after? You will get a lot of noise if you use few samples, but it also depends on what kind of lighting you use or the kind of surfaces you are using. Or maybe you need to render at a low resolution...

Comment: Read this answer to understand where noise comes from: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have more cycles noise just render with less samples and have glossy materials. Make sure reflective caustics are on, that will give you fireflies.

Comment: I think i got it the inverse way than anyone else. Thanx!