# Cycles Render Pixleated when rendering (Example of a minecraft image)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

[image: Minecraft example]

So when I do a cycle render for a picture/video why is it really pixelated/fuzzy when its rendered??

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the samples of the rendering.

[image]

For further information:

[How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Comment: I have changed the samples like you said but its still pixelated/fuzzy

Comment: Have you set it to at least 1000?

Comment: In the sampling?

Comment: Yes, in the sampling

Comment: Yes, it's still fuzzy.