# Noisy picture with no fireflies

Tags: noise-reduction

I made this picture with 6000 samples. No fireflies but still so noisy. I read a lot of articles to get rid of fireflies but I just need to clear my pic. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Did you disable caustics?

Comment: The caustics are enabled on this image. If I turn it off the result is darker but the noise is still there

Comment: Download and install [Blender's latest experimental build](https://builder.blender.org/download/) (For future readers this might be included in Blender by default) and install it, then open your .blend file in experimental and enable "Denoiser" under the Render Layers tab, then try rendering.

Comment: With all that glass have you experimented with changing the Glass Shader Distribution from say "Beckmann" to "Sharp"?

Comment: Do you have any mesh lights? They are the main source of any noise in cycles. If you have some try replacing them with actual lamps. It will remove most of the noise if not all.

Comment: Are you using [Light portals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/render/cycles/lamps.html#render-cycles-lamps-area-portals)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Answer (score 3):

You can turn on the new denoising feature that was presented in Blender 2.79. Please download Blender 2.79 [Here](https://www.blender.org/download/) and then follow the instructions presented below.

---

**Step 1.**

Open render layers. 
[image]

**Step 2.**

Check the box that says denoising.

[image]

---

Hopes this helps a lot of people

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the indirect lighting value, should help with reducing a majority of the noise.

[image: Indirect Lighting]

Also you can use a despeckle node in the compositor to help reduce noise.

[image: despeckle node]

Comment: The indirect lighting value is 100 at the moment so it won't help. I'll try the despeckle node

Comment: The despeckle node didn't help..... with 0.5 threshold it is still noisy, with 0.02 threshold it becomes blury

Comment: Hmm... That's odd, are you using a HDRI?

Comment: Also could you upload a copy of your .blend file, it'll make it easier to find a solution

Comment: how can I upload it? can't find

Comment: Ahh find it, but it's more than 30Mb

Comment: You can upload your .blend file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste a link by editing your question.

Comment: If you have Google Drive or OneDrive upload it to that and get a shareable link for the file

Comment: Also if the size of the lamps are small that could cause noise in your scene, try up-scaling the size of your lamps in your scene (only if they're overly small)

Comment: "The indirect lighting value is 100" - just try 10 instead of 100. But don't go lower than 10-5 because the realism will suffer.