# Noise on cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, noise-reduction

How do I remove the noise on renders?

All my output has noise on the shadows.

[image: sample render with noise]

This is a png render using cycles renderer.

Comment: Increase the number of samples.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles

Answer (score 1):

How many samples are you rendering with?

It looks like your scene has some problems with fireflies, pixels, that always stay white regardless of how many samples you set up.

> Cycles is a wonderful renderer, capable of some exquisite lighting
>   effects. However, sooner or later, you will encounter the problem of
>   fireflies, which are isolated bright pixels scattered over various
>   parts of the image. Unlike simple noise (which can be reduced by
>   increasing the number of render samples, or alternatively by simple
>   filtering), fireflies are caused by numerical instabilities in the
>   rendering computation, because after all computers can only calculate
>   the formulas to a finite precision. They seem an inevitable
>   consequence of trying to use realistic physics formulas to create our
>   renders.

[source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Cycles_Fireflies)

This guide really helped me to get rid of the fireflies & noise in our scene.
Especially no.6 Use clamping.

https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies

Answer (score -1):

Get your self a version of Blender with the Denoise feature: http://graphicall.org/444
I use it all the time.
[image]

You enable it in the Scene settings and just render as usual. The feature will reduce the amount of noise in your renders but might produce error if the sample count is too low.

Comment: please add more detail to your answer. What version do you mean? How is the denoise feature used? what do the settings do? etc, etc.

Answer (score -1):

The denoising feature is great but you will first want to try turning up the number of samples or turning off caustics. after that tryout denoising, you have to download one of the versions of blender that aren't completely bug free but, give it a go