# too much light causes noise

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, volumetrics, noise-reduction

Usually happens the opposite.. but today I have too much noise caused by too much light! (at least, I suppose It is because of that...)

[image: problem]

I have also Volume scatter and absorption applied to a cyclinder that surround an area lamp

[image: lamp]

[image: nodes]

Here my setups:

[image: setup]

light:

[image: light]

and there's also an environment texture:

[image: env text]

It is a part of the scene where all the lights are on for a while:

[image: all lights on]

any idea on how to get rid of all this noise? It occurs only when all the lights are on.. as You can see from this render (same samples)

[image: doesn't happen]

Comment: Using volume scatter will always increase noise. To get rid of it you need more samples. rad: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles

Comment: Doubling the samples solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

As cegaton suggested, I've increased the number of samples (doubled) and the noisy decreased so much!! :)

[image: more samples]

Comment: you can also try the denoiser feature on the latest build https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/86225/1853