# Shattered Glass Rendering Issues

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, shaders

I am a newbie in Blender. This is my second project. I thought of trying out Andrew Price's famous [glass shatter tutorial](https://%20www.youtube.com/watch?v=9L8qOq1Shiw) from BlenderGuru.

At this stage I thought of rendering and seeing how my images look. However, the material look was not very good. Firstly, the shattered glass pieces look nothing like in the video. Second, the glass shard particles seem to have too much grain (is that same as fireflies) and don't even look similar to what the video has.

I tried increasing compression factor and increasing samples, but neither helped much. I have been using the usual glass BSDF shader. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. How do I get image quality without grains like in the video. Would I need to use mix shaders with alpha to create glass material from scratch? Is it the lighting (I tried putting a screen behind my glass and that made things look a bit better, but still nowhere close)? Is it some rendering configuration?

---

Updates: I used the suggestions below from the link by Ray Mairlot (all of them: increased samples to 3000, tried progressive refine, tried the de-noise option from v2.79, made no of light bounces equal, added filter glossy, increased light sources, checked no caustics). I also changed by background to black. You can find all these changes in the updated blender file attached. Things improved a bit, but its still not close to Andrew's render (Updated image attached). I think I am missing something basic about the glass material or lighting.

Maybe having a look at the blender file might help ?

[Updated Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B81puWwIdvStNjN0VmxYYmk1eWc/view?usp=sharing ]

Updated Image:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Comment: I will try all of the replies (some I have already without much benefit) and get back on whether it solves my problem or not. Thanks so much.

Comment: @RayMairlot: I tried your updates and it improved things a bit, but still not close to Andrew's render. Please see updated question and updated files.

Comment: Can anybody help please ? I have been stuck at this step for like a week !

Comment: Please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend  files and use the built-in image uplaoder instead of linking to images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post