# why am I getting weird pepper shadows

Tags: shadows

the brows are making weird shadows. I am using a sun lamp

[image: the brows are making weird sadows]

Comment: Is the speckled pattern which looks weird? If so, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4980/599

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have enabled ambient occlusion in your viewport. You can control it in the Properties region ‣ Shading.

For more info, see the [Shading Panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html#shading-panel) manual chapter.