# How do I set the Seed value to 0 under the Sampling tab?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, noise-reduction

The seed value keeps resetting to the default value after I set it to 0, once I render a frame. I want to eliminate all noise from the final rendered image.

Comment: It shouldn't reset to default value. Probably you set up a keyframe for it which will make the value to change itself if not the same as with keyframe value. Screenshot of your settings would clarify this a bit

Comment: Make sure you didn't tick the *Use different seed values* button. Also have in mind that setting the seed to 0 doesn't eliminate all noise.

Comment: The seed value does not determine the amount of noise. Noise will be lessened by increasing the number of samples. The seed value is there so that you can change the noise pattern from frame to frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are misunderstanding the meaning of the **seed** value.

Seed is **not** how much *noise* there will be in your render. Seed is basically the pattern the noise will have. Noise is a natural byproduct of the way Cycles (and any ray-tracing renderer) renders the scene. There are many methods for [eliminating noise in Blender](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies), but the primary method is to raise the [**samples**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles).

There are so many resources on this topic, because it is really the major factor in whether a scene feasible to render. If we could render everything with one sample, we wouldn't really need to worry about render times, as long as our poly-count didn't exceed our memory.