# how to produce a Silk/Satin material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, shaders

I have two lamps, a plane with an emission shader and even world lighting turned on, why does my scene appear so grainy? I have turned up render samples, clamp indirect is now at 3.

What can I do to make a silky looking pillow that doesn't look so grainy? Plenty of screen shots below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of: [How to avoid noisy renders in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be using glass shaders with high roughness to produce a satin-like effect. Glass shaders can cause a lot of noise and would not seem an ideal fit for cloth (which is essentially opaque). You might be able to get a suitable effect using the Velvet shader or something like the following :

[image: satin material]

The satin is effectively a diffuse material with an element of glossiness - but glossiness that behaves subtly different to a smooth flat surface. In addition, the reflection off the glossy surface has quite a high roughness with a hint of the 'base' color (since the 'shine' is a mix of diffuse from some fibres of the cloth and glossy from others - so the usual dielectric rule of uncolored reflction doesn't apply here) - hence the Mix node to allow the reflection color to be adjusted. The Fresnel with a high value allows the amount of 'shine' to be adjusted and the Power node adjusts how the glossiness varies based on angle.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up using a texture but this could have worked just fine too. Thank you!!