# Get rid of /reduce Noise in Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, customization, noise-reduction

Im new to 3D object creation(2 weeks at most) and I was wondering if there is a way to reduce if not get rid of the noise when rendering using the cycles render.

thank you for the answers.

[image: sample of cycles render noise]

Comment: Any basic tutorial for using cycles will point out how the number of samples works and what one can do to reduce the noise. I would suggest doing at least minimal amount of research and learning before using it. There are plenty of answers even here on Blender Stack Exchange: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles

Answer (score 0):

There are some general tips and guidelines, I am sure you can find something in Google as well, this article made a while ago is still today relevant and can help you to understand more about it:

https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies

**Edit:**

The guidelines are:

1. Use Bigger Light Sources (Bigger lamps or blurred HDRI)
2. Use Bigger Shadow Sizes
3. Use "Multiple Importance Sampling" for HDRs
4. Use 'Filter Glossy'
5. Check "No Caustics" (Trade-off losing some of the light information)
6. Use "Clamping" (Trade-off dampening highlights)
7. More Samples (Trade-off more render time)

For simple projects, I recommend you to enable Simplify:

[image]

Essentially it simplifies your shaders, mostly glossy shaders, to render faster, this will give you the advantage to increase render samples, thus, decreasing noise areas.