# How can I remove these little artifacts from my rendered image?

Tags: rendering, artifacts, noise-reduction

[image]

I've read that too many reflections can cause these artifacts, but I couldn't find a solution to remove them. My sampling was set to 512.

Comment: Your Picture looks perfect to me. What`s your problem? What are the 'artifacts' you refer to?

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles