# Getting rid of reflective artifacts when using Cycles

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, artifacts

I cannot find a way to fix this issue. I tried higher sampling but the artifact still appears. If you look at the image, I added a light behind the lens. But there are fireflies/artifacts in the surrounding faces. How can I resolve this issue? Is this something to do with my mesh?

My settings are:
Cycles render
75% Render
1000 Sampling
Zero Compression 8 Bit

Comment: Ok, fireflies. A cycles nightmare. A few things I would like to know. 1. How many samples have you done? 2. What is the lens material. 3. What is the foam material? 4. How have you constructed the light source? An image of the scene would be helpfull. The mesh will have little effect on the render FYI, it will mostly be shaders, light sources and volumetrics. And a quick afterthought, what are the image dimentions?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the denoising, also you can change clamp indirect to reduce light reflection

Comment: @Bigfoot Blondy

Okay, I'm just using basic shadres for this. No NORMALS and TEXTURES.