# How do you get Rid of The Noisy Stuff?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, image

[image: The Image looks kind of Noisy How do I fix that?]

I was wondering how to make it not noisy. I looked at the one there already was and It didn't work.

Comment: This is a common question, and something that 3D artists have been trying to eliminate since the inception of ray tracing. You mention the previous post did not help you, but please read through all the responses to this question. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles
They help provide some insight into what noise is, why it is there, and how to reduce it.
Please note that posting a duplicate question is not encouraged, even if the previous question did not help you, unless you add content specific to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Cycles Render, there is a really cool feature named Denoising, which is on Render Layers tab. Tick it on and it will actually denoise your render, making it look better even with less samples. As far as I remember, it's available since version 2.78.

[image: Denoising]

Comment: Hi. Welcome and thanks for the answer, however the question is tagged with the 'blender-render' tag, meaning they are using the internal render engine, not Cycles (unless they have incorrectly tagged it, which is possible).

Comment: I don't have any of that...

Answer (score 0):

Trex, you could try increasing the quality of the final render as you're using blender-internal render:

[image]

It's set to 50% as default