# Can't figure out why this looks so grainy

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to do a project for one of my classes and i keep trying to fix the lighting and graininess (if that's a word). I've already watched a ton of lighting videos by blender guru and how to fix fireflies and im pretty sure im missing some key parts to fixing this image so i was wondering if anyone knows some things to help me out.[image: Really grainy picture cant fix]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Comment: I guess the first thing to check is in the Properties panel > Render > Sampling > Samples > Render value. Increase it.

Comment: Hi, add (or show) the relevant details you used to get that image, to let others judge/compare

Answer (score 1):

These are the fastest ways.
If you are not in Cycles Render then switch to Cycles and on the Render Layer tick mark Denoising.

[image]

If that does not give you the desired effect then increase the Render Samples as well , at the Sampling section, but will increase your render time.

[image]

These two settings usually solve the problem.

Sometimes I find that unticking the Reflective Caustics and the Refractive Caustics will improve some scenes. These settings are under the Light Paths settings under Sampling settings.

[image]