# How do I get rid of these weird light reflections on the floors and walls?

Tags: lighting

[image]

Hello, I am currently working on a 3D scene and this has happened to me several times by now and I still haven't found a solution. Increasing light bounces or samples doest seem to work.

This rendder has 215 samples and MIN 4 light bounces, max 4 light bounces.

Comment: Use more samples and avoid the denoiser

Comment: Rrad: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/86225/1853

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you so much!