# Spotting in a lightbulb render

Tags: lighting

I keep getting spotting in my render preview on a lightbulb I'm making, it doesn't seem to be anything to do with my hardware as I've rendered far more complex scenes than this more of something I'm missing either in the lighting or the object settings, can anyone help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXTJc.jpg

Comment: This effect is called fireflies. You can find some suggestions on how to fix this in the following article: https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles