# Was i misinformed?. GPU vs. CPU rendering

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting

I was told that my AMD RX580 should be compatible with cycles render. But when i choose cycles and then GPU it becomes grey'ed out, If it's not compatible i need to definitely stay way from cycles renders until i get a proper CPU cooler as the temps get really high during a cycles render. But if my GPU is supported then what am i doing wrong that it won't let me utilize my GPU over the CPU?

[image]

Comment: Drivers are all up to date and everything so am i missing some kind of setup within Blender to make the GPU work?.

Comment: Did you choose which device should be used for GPU render in Blender user prefs? Did you allow Blender to get access to the GPU from OS management? (differs depending on OS and GPU, but n your case that probably could be Catalyst control center)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i'm going to look into that right now. I'll let you know if that was the case or not.

Comment: Okay that's definitely what it was, thank you . The temps stay under 60 degrees on both CPU and GPU. But how do i reduce the noise in the render?.

Comment: Reducing noise in render is absolutely another question which often depends on a given setup but generally already described in answers like https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles

Comment: Thanks again i'll look into it.