# Blender 2.8 eevee rendering noise

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, noise-reduction

I am seeing a lot of noise when using eevee to render. Attached is a mesh where you will see the noise is very heavy at the bottom of the iconosphere. This noise is only seen with metallic materials. Is there anyway to get rid of it?[image]

Comment: Duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles

Comment: @morph3us, your link only addresses cycles render, not eevee

Comment: in the properties window, click on the camera symbol (the "render" context).
open up the "sampling" section and increase the viewport samples. DOes this affect your problem?

Comment: No, that did not work. Still see the noise.

Comment: could you share the scene? i'd have a quick look around.

Comment: @morph3us, updated with my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to increase both sampling and resolution. Depending on the complexity of your mesh, you may not need as high a resolution. Attached are the screenshots for the settings I used. Note - these settings apply to EEVEE render.

[image]

[image]