# I've got strange rendering artifacts; how to avoid it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm quite new to Blender and Cycles render engine, so I need some help to understand how I've got these rendering artifacts and how to fix them.

[image: Three test tubes and the nasty nose and white pixels]

The overall picture is very noisy and there are a lot of anomalous white pixels.

The whole scene looks like this.

[image: The scene]

The sphere is used as the source of light and has the emission shader.

[image: Sphere Emission Shader]

Each test tube is imported from another file and has Glass BSDF shader.

[image: Glass Shader]

I've bumped up a little numbers of light paths transparency and bumps (don't know what does that mean, actually), but I think it does not help much.

[image: Light Paths]

I don't know what else to add, so here it is. What should I do?

Comment: Hello :). These white dots are called *Fireflies* and usually appear when the lights are way too strong. Here is a [comprehensive article on how to get rid of them](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies) from the BlenderGuru himself.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles